# security issues in ASP EnableEventValidation

Tags: asp.net, security

I am using `EnableEventValidation` to prevent users from changing values in form data, specifically email addresses (to prevent users from putting in emails to potentially spam others from my server). I have `EnableEventValidation` set to true, but I am wanting to know if there are any security issues where users could get around this or bypass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, EVENTVALIDATION+VIEWSTATEMAC is a safe combo. If VIEWSTATEMAC is not enabled, then it is possible to tamper with EVENTVALIDATION and add/edit the values ASP will take as valid. There is more info here:

http://www.jardinesoftware.net/2012/02/06/asp-net-tampering-with-event-validation-part-1/
http://www.jardinesoftware.net/2012/02/01/viewstatemac-seriously-enable-it/

However, it is not recommended to rely on ASP (or any other framework) automated validation systems for security.

Hope it helps!